# Editing a CSV with powershell, but only one column is unexpectedly exported

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to take a CSV, a tab delimited txt file, and change one of the columns from 'last name, first' to ' First name last name'. I think I am nearly there with getting it into the right format for another program, but my exported file only has one column, the one with the name that I edited.

```
Import-CSV -Path import.txt  -Delimiter "`t" -Header @("col0", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "cal1", "cal2", "cal3", "cal4", "cal5") |
foreach{ 
    $last,$first = $_.col3 -split ", "
    new-object psobject -Property @{name = "$first $last"}
    $_
} |
Export-CSV done.txt -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation

(Get-Content -Path done.txt ).Replace('"','') | Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
Set-Content -Path done.txt
(gc done.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content done.txt
```

I tried to export to txt or csv. The last two lines is more for format, but I have tried excluding them. There's also no headers. so I added them and took them off at the end. Without adding new-object, it doesn't work at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Modify the `.col3` property of each input object directly - no need for `New-Object`.

  - In fact it was the object emitted by `new-object psobject -Property @{name = "$first $last"}` that caused your problem: as the *first* output object, it *locked in the columns* for the `Export-Csv` call, which meant that only a `name` column was exported.
- Use [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) in lieu of [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) to produce the CSV (TSV) data *in memory*, as a stream of lines, which allows you to skip the header line via [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) `-Skip 1` and then write the remaining lines to your output file with [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content).

```bash
Import-CSV -Path import.txt  -Delimiter "`t" -Header col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4, cal5 |
  ForEach-Object{ 
    $last, $first = $_.col3 -split ", "
    $_.col3 = "$first $last"
    $_
  } | 
  ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation |
  Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
  Set-Content -Encoding utf8 done.txt
```

Note:

- I've added `-Encoding utf8` to the `Set-Content` call as a reminder that you may want to control the character encoding explicitly; given that `Set-Content` uses the system's active legacy ANSI code page by default; note that `-Encoding utf8` invariably produces UTF-8 files *with a BOM* in Windows PowerShell.
- In *Windows PowerShell*, you get *no* control over whether the fields in the output CSV (TSV) data are double-quoted or not - they *all* are, but for well-behaved CSV / TSV readers that shouldn't make a difference.
- In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md):

  - You *do* get control over the quoting behavior of `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Export-Csv` via the `-UseQuotes` and `-QuoteFields` parameters.
  - Also, these two cmdlets now support a `-NoHeader` switch to avoid emitting / writing a header row, and the use of `-NoTypeInformation` is no longer necessary.
  - Additionally, (BOM-less) UTF-8 is now the *consistent* default encoding. If desired, you can still request a BOM with `-Encoding utf8BOM`

Therefore, in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* the code can be simplified to the following:

```bash
# PS 7+ only
Import-CSV -Path import.txt  -Delimiter "`t" -Header col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4, cal5 |
  ForEach-Object{ 
    $last, $first = $_.col3 -split ", "
    $_.col3 = "$first $last"
    $_
  } | 
  Export-Csv done.txt -Delimiter "`t" -UseQuotes Never -NoHeader
```

The above omits double-quoting from the fields and creates a BOM-less UTF-8 output file.

Comment: Your answers are always great

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @An-dir, and I appreciate the nice feedback.

Comment: Hey Thanks so much for the detailed response! I ended up mixing some of my ending in, solely because the old software it's going into is pretty picky and I couldn't get the format to match right. This is super helpful though, and makes so much more sense than what I was doing.

Comment: PowerShell Core also gives you control of whether or not there is a BOM using `-Encoding` with values of `utf8`, `utf8BOM`, and `utf8NoBOM`. The help shows them in ALL CAPS in the SYNTAX section.

Comment: Thanks, @lit: I've added a hint re `utf8BOM` to the answer. The [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) help topic, for instance, isn't consistent regarding the specific case of the identifiers, but - as usual in PowerShell - case doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

With an example source and an example target string I would have been happy, but I guess you need something like this

```
Get-Content -Path import.txt | foreach {
     $tmp = $_ -split "\t";
     $tmp[3] = $tmp[3] -replace "^([^,]*), ?(.*)",'$2 $1';
     $tmp -join "`t"
 } | Set-Content -Path import.txt
```

It reads the text file line by line.
Splits the cols by tab.
Changes the fourth col by taking the first part before the comma and (may be followed by a space) takes the following chars as second part. Second part now becomes first, followed by a space and the first part.
Now all cols get joined joined back together by tab.